# Windows Batch For Loop Filenames with Exclamation Point "!" Problems

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Exclamation Points are my bane with Windows Batch. Say I want to just skip filenames with an `!` in them.

I know for checking regular text in variables in a for loop, I can run:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*) do (
set fname=%%~na
if not "!fname!"=="!fname:text=!" ECHO File contains the word "text"
)
```

But how do I specify an exclamation point?

I've tried to escape it with ^: `"!fname:^!=!"`

Then I see that with enabledelayedexpansion you need a `^^!` to escape the character. So I tried that with no luck. Then I thought maybe three `^^^!` two to escape delayedexpansion and one in the filename...

No luck...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following **commented** script unveils the secrets:

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo --- disabled delayed expansion: real file names
FOR /R "D:\bat\Unusual Names" %%G in (*exc*) DO (
  echo(%%~nG 
)
ENDLOCAL
echo(

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
echo --- enabled delayed expansion chokes down unescaped exclamation marks
echo                               (or expands !variables!)
FOR /R "D:\bat\Unusual Names" %%G in (*exc*) DO (
  echo(%%~nG 
)
ENDLOCAL
echo(

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo --- SET variables under delayed expansion DISABLED
echo       and USE them with delayed expansion ENABLED as follows
FOR /R "D:\bat\Unusual Names" %%G in (*exc*) DO (
  set "_fname=%%~nG"
  call :replace
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    if "!_fname!"=="!_gname!" (
      echo(!_fname! == !_gname!
    ) else (
      echo(!_fname! ## !_gname!
    )
  ENDLOCAL
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:replace
  set "_gname=%_fname:exc!=%"
goto :eof
```

**Result**: `D:\bat\SU\1552419.bat`

```
--- disabled delayed expansion: real file names
01exclam!ation
02exc!lam!ation
04exc!lam!ation!OS!%OS%

--- enabled delayed expansion chokes down unescaped exclamation marks
                              and expands unescapet percent signs
01exclamation
02excation
04excationWindows_NT%OS%

--- SET variables under delayed expansion DISABLED
      and USE them with delayed expansion ENABLED as follows
01exclam!ation == 01exclam!ation
02exc!lam!ation ## 02lam!ation
04exc!lam!ation!OS!%OS% ## 04lam!ation!OS!%OS%
```

Comment: Thank you. I spent a bit of time trying to digest that and with some trial and error I managed to get it working... I hope... Thanks for the detailed response.